# Change background image position using mouse drag like facebook cover photo

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is where I am so far: https://codepen.io/chavdar84/pen/pKvXbq

I'm trying to limit the drag to the borders of the image.

```
var start_y;
var mouseDown = false;
var move = true;
$('.image').mousedown( function() {
    mouseDown = true;
});

$(document).mouseup( function() {
    mouseDown = false;
});

$('.image').mouseenter( function(e) {
    start_y = e.clientY;
});

$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    // var window_width = $('.image').outerWidth();
    // var element_height = $('.image').outerHeight();
    var newPos = e.clientY - start_y;
    if (mouseDown) {
        if (parseInt($('.image').css('background-position-y')) >= -230) {
            $('.image').css('background-position-y', '+=' + newPos);
        }
        console.log(start_y);

    }
    start_y = e.clientY;        
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I could figure out:

```js
var imgWidth;
 var imgHeight;
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/860/550/?image=316';
 
 $(img).on('load', function() {
  imgWidth = img.width;
  imgHeight = img.height;
  $('#image').css('background-image', 'url(' + img.src + ')');
 });
 
 //var newWidth = (400 * 100) / w;
 //console.log(newWidth);

 var start_y;
 var newPos;
 var curPos = $('#image').css('background-position-y');
 var mouseDown = false;
 var move = true;
 $('#image').mousedown( function(e) {
  mouseDown = true;
  //console.log(e.clientY);
 });
 
 $(document).mouseup( function() {
  mouseDown = false;
  $('.image').css('background-position-y', curPos)
 });
 
 $('#image').mouseenter( function(e) {
  start_y = e.clientY;
 });
  
 $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
  newPos = e.clientY - start_y;
  start_y = e.clientY;
  if (mouseDown) {
   $('#image').css('background-position-y', '+=' + newPos);
   curPos = parseInt($('#image').css('background-position-y'));
   if (curPos > 0) curPos = 0;
   if (curPos < -50) curPos = -50;
   $('#image').css('background-position-y', curPos);
  }
 });
```

```css
#image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div id="image"></div>

</body>
```

Getting the image's dimensions after setting the background to cover is a whole different issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by calculating height of the image. Please be more precise with the actual problem next time.

Following is the one way to approach this [codepen](https://codepen.io/rehanumar/pen/dKoGMd?editors=0110)

```
(function() {   
  var imageHeight = 0;
  var initialMouseY = 0;
  var scrollY = 0;
  var isAllowDrag = false;
  var scrollDelta = 0;

  function dragImage(e) {
    scrollY = initialMouseY - e.clientY;
    scrollDelta = imageHeight - e.target.scrollHeight;
    if (isAllowDrag && scrollY < scrollDelta) {
      e.target.style.backgroundPositionY = "-" + scrollY + "px";
    }
  }

  function afterDrag(e) {
    e.target.style.cursor = "-webkit-grab";
    isAllowDrag = false;
  }

  function beforeDrag(e) {
    e.target.style.cursor = "-webkit-grabbing";
    initialMouseY = e.clientY;
    isAllowDrag = true;
  }

  function addImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://picsum.photos/800/400/?image=316"
    imageHeight = image.height;
    $(".image").css('backgroundImage', "url('https://picsum.photos/800/400/? 
    image=316')");
  }

  $(".image").on("mouseup", afterDrag);
  $(".image").on("mousemove", dragImage);
  $(".image").on("mousedown", beforeDrag);
  $(window).on("load", addImage);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the different solution!